# is there a way to put my radiobox and label in the same line because it's not working for me?

Tags: html, css, forms

Here are the problems:

1. the "definitely" radiobox and label are not on the same line i tried everything and it still didn't work
2. the check box overlaps with the label as you can see on the screenshot when minimized
3. the background picture is zoomed, the left output on the screenshot is perfect i want that output
   where did i go wrong?

```css
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-image: linear-gradient( 115deg, rgba(58, 58, 158, 0.8), rgba(136, 136, 206, 0.7)), url(https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/testable-projects-fcc/images/survey-form-background.jpeg);
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.4;
  color: var(--color-white);
  margin: 0;
}

input {
  display: block;
  margin: 2em;
  width: 90%;
}

.labelr {
  width: unset;
  margin: 0 0.5em 0 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

select {
  margin: 2em;
  display: block;
  width: 90%;
}

.radio {
  border: none;
  padding: 2em;
}

form {
  width: 70vw;
  margin: auto auto;
  background-color: rgba(27, 27, 50, 0.8);
  max-width: 800px;
  min-width: 300px;
  padding-top: 2em;
  border-radius: 0.3rem;
  padding-bottom: 2em;
}

label {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  margin: 2em;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: 400;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.2;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  font-size: 1.125rem;
}

input,
button,
select,
textarea {
  margin: ;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  line-height: inherit;
}

.check-option {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  /* Reduce the spacing between options */
}

label {
  margin-right: -200px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.bio {
  display: block;
}

textarea {
  margin: 2.5em;
  margin-top: -20px;
}

.submit-button {
  display: block;
  width: 90%;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  background: #37af65;
  color: white: border-radius: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: em;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;500;600;700&display=swap">

</head>

<body>
  <h1 id="title">freeCodeCamp Survey Form</h1>
  <p id="description">Thank you for taking the time to help us improve the platform</p>
  <form id="survey-form">
    <label id="name-label" for="name"> Name</label>
    <input required id="name" type="text" placeholder="enter your name" />
    <label id="email-label" for="email">Email</label>
    <input required id="email" type="email" placeholder="enter your email" />
    <label id="number-label">Age(optional)</label>
    <input required id="number" type="number" min="18" max="120" placeholder="age" />
    <label>Which option best describes your current role?</label>
    <select id="dropdown">
      <option>
        student
      </option>
      <option>
        Fulltime Job
      </option>
      <option>
        Full Time Learner
      </option>
      <option>
        Prefer not to say
      </option>
      <option>
      </option>
    </select>
    <fieldset class="radio">
      <div></div>
      <label>
  Would you recommend freeCodeCamp to a friend?
</label>
      <br></br>
      <div class="radio-option">
        <input type="radio" name="radio" value="definitely" class="labelr" /><label>definitely</label>
      </div>

      <div class="radio-option">
        <input type="radio" name="radio" value="maybe" class="labelr" /><label>maybe</label>
      </div>
      <div class="radio-option">
        <input type="radio" name="radio" value="not-sure" class="labelr" /><label>not sure</label>
      </div>

    </fieldset>
    <div class="check-option">
      <label for="frontend">Frontend</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="frontend" value="frontend" />
    </div>

    <div class="check-option">
      <label for="backend">Backend</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="backend" value="backend" />

    </div>
    <label for="bio" class="bio">Any comments or suggestions</label>
    <textarea id="bio" name="bio" rows="3" cols="30" placeholder="I like coding on the beach..."></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" class="submit-button" id="submit" />
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

---

Desired output vs the current output

[image: target look vs my results]

Comment: Adding `input[type="radio"] { display: inline-block; }` to your CSS will fix your problem.

Comment: @Gerard thanks a lot it works, can you help me out with the remaining 2 problems please?

Comment: `input[type="checkbox"] { margin-left: 0; }` should be adjusted. Setting it to for instance 20 pixels will create space between the label and the checkbox itself.

Comment: I believe removing `width: 70vw;` from the form in your CSS gives the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

For 1:
Remove `display: block;` from your radio input element, the one with `class="labelr"`.

By default, block elements can not be placed next to each other. If you remove `display: block;` the display will change to the default `display: inline-block`, which can be placed next to another inline-block or inline element.

For 2:
Place your `<input>` above your `<label>` like so:

```
<div class="check-option">
  <input type="checkbox" id="frontend" value="frontend">
  <label for="frontend">Frontend</label>   
</div>
```

You'll probably want to remove the `width:90%` from the `<input>` as well as that is making things more difficult.

For 3: On the `<body>` element, you could add:

```
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed;
```

I'm not sure if that is the desired effect though.

In general:
Try not to use negative margin or padding even though it might seem like a good idea. It will makes things messy later on. I never use it.

Be careful with putting styles on element selectors. You put `width:90%` on ALL `input` elements though you probably don't want that for all elements.

Making a form with all these elements is quite difficult. Don't give up!

Comment: thanks a lot @RenevandenBerg your solutions for the first and third question worked, and the reason i put 90% on the input elements was because when it's on default the text box overflows from the form borders and setting it to 90% worked. if you have a better solution then i'm happy to learn from you.

Comment: For the inputs, I would put the width to 100% and remove the margin, and instead set padding on element `<form id="survey-form">`. Also, you can target text inputs only with `input[type="text"]`.

Answer (score 0):

please avoid to direct use of CSS on label, textarea, and inputs this will messy . for better practice and clean code use classes and id for css

css

```
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-image: linear-gradient( 115deg, rgba(58, 58, 158, 0.8), rgba(136, 136, 206, 0.7)), url(https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/testable-projects-fcc/images/survey-form-background.jpeg);
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.4;
  color: var(--color-white);
  margin: 0;
}

input {
  /* display: block; */
  /* margin: 2em; */
  /* width: 90%; */
}

.labelr {
  width: unset;
  margin: 0 0.5em 0 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

select {
  margin: 2em;
  display: block;
  width: 90%;
}

.radio {
  border: none;
  padding: 2em;
}

form {
  width: 70vw;
  margin: auto auto;
  background-color: rgba(27, 27, 50, 0.8);
  max-width: 800px;
  min-width: 300px;
  padding-top: 2em;
  border-radius: 0.3rem;
  padding-bottom: 2em;
}

label {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  /* margin: 2em; */
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: 400;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.2;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  font-size: 1.125rem;
}

input,
button,
select,
textarea {
  margin: ;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  line-height: inherit;
}

.check-option {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  /* Reduce the spacing between options */
}

label {
  margin-right: -200px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.bio {
  display: block;
}

textarea {
  margin: 2.5em;
  margin-top: -20px;
}

.submit-button {
  display: block;
  width: 90%;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  background: #37af65;
  color: white; 
  border-radius: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: em;
}
```

by this you'll see your [labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/489C6.png) radio labels arrangement look better , just use css by classes.